# Criação de mais de uma tabela Android Studio (SQLite)

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou tentando desenvolver um aplicativo mobile para um trabalho final da minha faculdade, é bem simples!

O aplicativo tem que guardar as informações  cadastradas no banco de dados.

Porém eu teria que criar 4 tabelas diferentes para armazenar os dados, as tabelas seriam: `Usuário`, `Aplicativo`, `Empresa` e `Funcionários`.

E depois de cadastrar realizar Selects que o professor quer.

**O Problema:** Eu não sei se é possível fazer essa criação de 4 tabelas diferentes no `Android Studio` e depois inserir dados nelas, para fazer os selects.

Eu já fiz antes um Aplicativo semelhante a esse, porém só usava 1 tabela.

Comment: O mesmo processo que você usa pra criar uma tabela, basta repetir e criar as quatro. No onCreate do SQLite não esqueça de dar o CREATE table 4x

Comment: Sim mas eu vou conseguir depois inserir os dados e fazer os selects dessas 4 tabelas ?

Comment: Claro, um banco de dados pode ter (praticamente) infinitas tabelas. Você só precisa fazer os métodos serem agnósticos quanto a qual tabela estão trabalhando (passando parametros) ou fazer um metodo pra cada tabela pra cada operacao.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi, você quer criar a tabela e já inserir os valores?

Você pode realizar quantas operações forem necessárias no `onCreate`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //Vamos criar as tabelas... 
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Usuario ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT )");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Aplicativo ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT )");
    //Seus demais INSERTS...

    /**
     * Agora vamos inserir os dados na tabela...
     **/

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Usuario values (1, 'Usuario Um')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Usuario values (2, 'Usuario Dois')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Usuario values (3, 'Usuario Tres')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Usuario values (4, 'Usuario Qautro')");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, utilizar banco de dados para persistir dados é muito comum, e para isso possui algumas alternativas.

1. Você pode montar uma API, o qual você consulta, e insere dados. Utilizando um servidor, com a linguagem que você quiser. Comunicando via JSON.
2. Se não tem uma certa necessidade de comunicação entre outros dispositivos, e deseja persistir esses dados localmente no dispositivo você pode usar alguma plataforma. Eu pessoalmente gosto do [DB Flow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow) ou até mesmo implementar "na mão" com a library `SQLiteOpenHelper`. [Tutorial do DEVMEDIA](http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-crud-com-android-studio-e-sqlite/32815)